# Dynamic controls and asp:button postback

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, postback

I'm having an issue saving page content to my database.  On a page, I have a bunch of dynamically added controls and a save button at the top of the page.  I am using client-side javascript to manipulate the controls.  One the user is finished, I would like him to click the save button and save all of the changes to my database (via server-side click event).  The problem, obviously, is that when the use clicks "save" the page posts back and I lose all of the javascript changes.  For simplicity, I'll layout the save button and one control.

HTML:

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="saveGames" runat="server" CssClass="saveGamesLbtn" OnClick="saveGames_Click" Text="Save"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
 
        <div id="controls" runat="server">
            
        </div>
</form>
```

PAGELOAD:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var games = {grab games from DB via LINQ};
    foreach (var game in games)
    {
        UpdatePanel uPanel = new UpdatePanel();
        uPanel.ID = "gamePanel_" + game.GameID.ToString();

        Label xpRewardLbl = new Label();
        xpRewardLbl.ID = "xpRewardLbl_" + game.GameID.ToString();
        xpRewardLbl.Text = "0xp";

        uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(xpRewardLbl);
        controls.controls.add(uPanel);
    }
}
```

On the "save" click, I want to parse through all labels to grab their changed state but the controls are being removed because their not reloaded in postback - if I reload them in postback, their state is lost.  If I could parse through all controls and save the data BEFORE postback, that would be fine too.  How do you go about achieving this?  I'm thinking something to do with the updatepanels will help me but i'm not sure how to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: how do you change labels? labels are labels and not input controls. You have to use input controls like textbox for the information to come back to server!

Comment: I have tons of input controls, all of those are handled by the client-side javascript.  To make my post simple and not confusing I just used a label.  Just pretend I have a button that increments the label by 1 everytime it's clicked (via javascript).  Then I click "save" which fires my server-side click event.  How do I capture the label's changed state from server-side code?

Comment: as I said, you cannot, as they are not input controls... they won't be send back to the server...

Comment: So you're saying I can't do this from server code:  string text = (Label)controls.FindControl({lbliD}).Text;

Comment: not with lables, but with textboxes

Comment: Dude, you're not getting this... OK, I do have a textBox.  I dynamically create a textBox and throw it into the "controls" div.  On creation, I set textBox.Text = "";  I have another button that changes the textBox.Text via Javascript.  If I click "save" and fire a server-side click event, the textBox loses its ".Text" state.  Again, how do I maintain the state??

Comment: Dude, you have to recreate the tb in the Page_OnInit event on every postback.

Comment: dude, you are manipulating a label here, your example:
`string text = (Label)controls.FindControl({lbliD}).Text`

This is not possible.

Comment: `Page_OnInit`, not `Page_Load`

Comment: OnInit is still not working.  The controls are not maintaining state.